# Solve theme installation problem?

Tags: errors

I am developing a theme but when I install this theme in my local server it say this message. what's the problem actually?

[image]

Comment: Is your installed WordPress version less than 4.4 and are you using Term Metadata?

Comment: The answer is obviously in the error message, just reread the error message. (***Term Metadata is a WordPress > 4.4 feature. Please upgrade your WordPress install***). Easy, issue solved

Answer (score 0):

Your theme is using taxonomy `term metadata` that did not become available until Version 4.4 of wordpress.

Refer to: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/10/23/4-4-taxonomy-roundup/ if you want to read up on this.

You need to upgrade your WordPress installation to 4.4 or above (latest is 4.5.1) or modify your theme.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress